# Looking at Projectlocker, Cloudforge, and Assembla Portfolio for Git Hosting - Any opinions?

Tags: git, dvcs, assembla, projectlocker

We're a small webdesign shop here and we want to get all our clients on a DVCS system that deploys our commits via sftp.

I've narrowed it down to Projectlocker, CloudForge and Assembla Portfolio.

There's also Beanstalk and Springloops but they'd end up being 2-4x the price of the other options for us. (300 projects is a lot to these hosts even though we're only 10-15gb)

Does anybody have any experience with Projectlocker, Cloudforge and/or Assembla Portfolio?

Is there a better solution that I'm missing out on? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assembla is a good option - the portfolio project is about to get a whole lot better with being able to create a space as a subset of another space.  As well as sharing ticket lists and repositories.

In general - the Assembla Portfolio project will work well for 300 projects, particularly if they share any elements, such as team.

You are able to deploy via sftp from git and a new product will let you run any script after a deploy on your servers.  Assembla is also starting to integrate with jenkins for unit testing.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anything that makes Assembla a better option than the others? Cloudforge and Projectlocker do the same things Assembla does, right?

Comment: I can't speak to better or worse when comparing to others.  They are all different.

Comment: Each product has it's ups and downs, and you have to really evaluate what your needs are.  For instance, jira is highly customizable, Assembla is very simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think that CollabNet CloudForge is the best option. It offer you unlimited users, unlimited projects, but limited Size to 2 GB with its Free Version. That is absolutely the best free option offered by the day I am writing these lines.

even when going for payed version, it will be 2$ per user per Month which is also the Best.

We will have also the scrum power of TeamForge, tickets, tracking ...

Answer (score 0):

I've had many years of success with projectlocker. I've used the free version for small projects. It works great. You can always upgrade if the project grows.